# Creating random polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, random

I have done a raster sampling analysis, wherein I extracted the raster values for a set of given points across different datasets.

How do I do the same using random polygons (instead of points) in QGIS?

Comment: There is no native tool for that but many ways to achieve it. Any requirements on their shape, size, position, etc.?

Comment: Just the size: 300m x 300m

Comment: So a square shaped polygon?

Comment: Create points, generate buffers with 150 m radius, take the envelopes?

Comment: Do you have random polygons or do you also want to create them?

Answer (score 4):

[Create random points](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?#random-points-in-extent) and from these, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Rectangles, ovals, diamonds`, select rectangles and set the size.

Comment: I am no sure, but I guess OP asks "how do I do raster sampling analysis using random polygons", although the title says something different.

Comment: Ups, you might be right. Indeed, the question is not clear. However, extracting raster values for polygons doen't really make sense, at least for me. So we will have to wait for the OP to clarify the situation.

Comment: Zonal Statistics tool, maybe.